# How to handle dependency files in a cross-platform manner?

Tags: java, windows

I'm working on updating an old app.  It has some dependency files that live in the same directory as the app.  Obviously this broke when Windows Vista came out (since it violates the API and Vista/7 now enforce that (XP didn't)).

Ideally, I'd like to avoid hardcoding anything into the app for just Windows.  I can live with that if I have to though.  I've already been down that path with pulling the APPDATA and LOCALAPPDATA environment variables, but that doesn't help any since they just give you the current user area...  I need these to live somewhere accessible for all users, and I'd like to obey the Windows API expectations that they go into the all user appdata area.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean cross platform and not just Vista compliant, the correct way is the Preferences API. Last time I tried that on Vista though, the system store didn't work, though.

If you just mean Vista, you can get the system environment variables and reference it that way.

Comment: We support Mac OS X and *nix operating systems as well, so I really would like to do it in a single fully cross-platform method.  However, if I have to do OS dependent coding, I can live with it.

Still, the problem remains that I haven't found a system environment variable that points to the all user appdata store.  I don't really want to try constructing it myself as that seems like it could be an error-prone process (especially if Microsoft changes the location for some reason in future versions of Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a Windows specific location...  I was confused at first because it's a hidden directory, but the "ALLUSERSPROFILE" environment variable seems to be the right location on Windows.

Still looking for something truly cross-platform if anyone knows of a way.

Comment: The preferences API is the the official true cross platform way (if they care enough to fix the bug http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6565257). I would say use the ALLUSERSPROFILE hack on windows, and the Preferences API everywhere else.

Comment: Looks like determining if it's Vista should be pretty easy.  Might even just attempt the hack only on Vista.